# Multi color input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is possible, using only css and/or JQuery, that the first "x" characters are in one color and the other are in another color, in an input field?

Comment: @RUJordan: Care to elaborate? I've never seen anything like that. If that's possible, there must be something I don't know :-D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170373/multiple-font-colors-in-an-input-tag

Comment: You can do it e.g for div elements, but not for input (as far as I tried to implement that): http://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/djuIx

Comment: @RUJordan wow, quick search but looks like it's a **workaround** rather than a direct solution which had seemed to exist derived from your quick comment *it is possible*. Anyway, that is a good idea and maybe the only way to achieve the same effect.

Comment: @KingKing I'm not really inclined to put more effort until the OP shows an effort. That was just a google search

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using gradient colors but it will not work on every browser.
For an example, using chrome specific css.

http://jsfiddle.net/pgd8z/

```
<input type="Text" Value="Testing colors" class="textbox" />

input {
  font-size: 2em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 10%, blue 10%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: There is a possible to use it in IE?