# Html Color only (*) symbol in input placeholder field in form

Tags: html, css, placeholder, html-input

I have the following code:

```
<input id="firstName" name="fname" type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="First Name *" required>
```

How can I color the (*) symbol in the placeholder value red without coloring the other text with it (being First Name text)?

Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you!
Al

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't possible  to change the color of certain text in a input :( you can try to use a contenteditable div

Comment: You should not be presenting label information in a placeholder string. As soon as the user clicks on the field, they will lose the information you are giving them. This is terrible UX.

Comment: @IMSoP thanks, I really enjoy a minimalist form of styling. With the way I have it, it disappears as soon as they start typing but not when they click, at least that is how it works in chrome, which isn't too bad I think. But I might put it outside of the input fields, I hope it doesn't clutter too much though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to change the color of certain text in a input :( you can try to use a `contenteditable` div:

```
<div class="input" contenteditable>First Name <span style="color:red;">*</span></div>
```

Then, you have to add and remove the placeholder with JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('.input').focus(function(){
        $(this).html('');
    });
    $('.input').blur(function(){
       if($(this).html()=='') this.innerHTML='First Name <span style="color:red;">*</span>';
    });
});
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c73bvvr7/)

Comment: Thanks, I assume this will be the closest way of doing this. Now I am wondering of whether I should include the placeholder values outside of the form as well. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :D Yes, it is best to put a label and required mark outside the input field, so as to make it easier on the user

Comment: Just bear in mind that this solution will take a little more js to add the required attribute, but it is a good practice to check inputs value with js anyway, you should not trust the html validation

Comment: @Baraa you should really consider using Hashem Qolami's answer, it is just CSS, and works beautifully

Answer (score 5):

One possible option could be using [`:valid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid) pseudo-class for the **required** `<input>` to make the absolutely positioned sibling element disappear — which is used as a placeholder under the input.

So, we can use `::before`/`::after` pseudo-elements over the absolutely positioned element to change the color of our pseudo-placeholder.

```css
.input-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.input-wrapper input {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.input-wrapper input:valid + .placeholder {
  display: none;
}

.input-wrapper .placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 2px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.input-wrapper .placeholder::before {
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  color: #999;
}

.input-wrapper .placeholder::after {
  content: " *";
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input id="firstName" name="fname" type="text" maxlength="50" required>
  <span class="placeholder" data-placeholder="First Name"></span>
</div>
```

It's worth noting that `:valid` pseudo-class is supported in IE10+.

Comment: I didn't think of that, awesome way to do it :D

Comment: @Hashem Qolami Thanks so I guess it is possible to do it this way and keep it as a type input!

Comment: @Hashem Qolami ...I implemented this code yet my input is coming out empty..am I missing something?

Comment: @Baraa Please provide an online example so that I can help better :-)

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't, like that. The best way to do this would be something like this SO answer: [Multiple font colors in an Input tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170373/multiple-font-colors-in-an-input-tag)

In essence, a second div is put over the input field, allowing for the change in colour.